# javax.usb UsbHostManager.getUsbService() properties is null

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the javax.usb library.

```java
import javax.usb.*;

public class PrinterCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            UsbServices usbServices = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
        } catch (UsbException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this simple code, but when I run it, I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-community/456/lib/idea_rt.jar=42049:/snap/intellij-idea-community/456/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/amiroof/Projects/Cinema/out/production/Cinema:/home/amiroof/Projects/Cinema/lib/mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:/home/amiroof/Projects/Cinema/lib/javax.usb.jar PrinterCheck
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Properties.getProperty(String)" because "properties" is null
    at javax.usb.UsbHostManager.getServicesName(UsbHostManager.java:96)
    at javax.usb.UsbHostManager.initialize(UsbHostManager.java:32)
    at javax.usb.UsbHostManager.getUsbServices(UsbHostManager.java:24)
    at PrinterCheck.main(PrinterCheck.java:9)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried reinstalling the library, but that didn't worked. I'm new to Java, so if I'm missing something obvious, please let me know.

Comment: Which library are you using? There are many third-party libraries supporting the javax.usb specification. You should specify the library and exact version number (e.g. the Github URL or the Maven coordinates of the library).

Comment: @k314159 this is where i downloaded it from. I can't remember the exact site. http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/javax.usb/javax.usb.jar.zip

Comment: It looks like you are omitting to set up the properties. You will need to check the documentation for that, but the jar file in this link contains only compiled class files, so finding documentation will be difficult.